# How to overlap multi mp3 files to one mp3 file with ffmpeg?

Tags: merge, ffmpeg, mp3, overlap

Hi all
I have multi mp3 files, each file have difference sound. Now i need overlap all of them to one file to have a mp3 file with all other sound. Can i do that with ffmpeg or other tool?

Thank for your help.

Comment: I want to achieve the same(overlapping multiple mp3 files into one) but in my android app . Searched alot but found nothing helpfull. Have you found solution for your problem. If yes please share knowledge . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMO, can't be done with ffmpeg.

I would decode all mp3 to .wav files and use Audacity to mix all sources to a single stereo .wav. Then, you can easily reencode this to mp3.

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)